# sharing 1 blutooth and 2 devices

Tags: bluetooth, screen-sharing

I have an automotive OBD2 computer reader connected to a bluetooth elm 327 reader. I can see info on my galaxy 5S or my galaxy tab 2 10.1 tablet.

Is it possible to read on both devices at same time? I have the tablet paired to the OBD2 device and the 5S paired to the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth can only connect two devices at once (please correct if wrong). So in my opinion you can't read on both devices at the same time.